# Creating a reference to objects

Tags: php, arrays

I can't really explain what I want to do, but I still try:

I am using an external API that responds with huge json-objects. I want to get parts of these with PHP in a dynamic way. For instance I would normally get the score by using `$json->stats->scores->score;`.

Now I want to have users to select different stats to display, so on their administration page they choose "Score", "Kills, "Wins", ... - Their selection will then be saved in a database (in a string like `Score,Kills,Wins`). Later on I will use `explode(',', $selection);` to receive an array representing all these selections.

Finally all the selected stats should be echo'ed - And this is the part I need help with.

```
$json->stats->scores->score // Score
$json->stats->kills         // Kills
$json->stats->numWins       // Wins
```

This is, how I need to adress each of these values. Now is there a way to create a reference to those, so I just can do something like the following?

```
$js['Score']; // = $json->stats->scores->score
$js['Kills']; // = $json->stats->kills
$js['Wins'];  // = $json->stats->numWins
```

I hope you understood my explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very unclear. Have you tried to decode json with second parameter as `true` and work with array? Show some real code example where you have difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all read [References Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) from the PHP manual.

Yes, you can create a reference using `&`. You can also - if you don't need to change the original values - just let out the `&` and create an array in a completely regular way.

**Code example**:

```
<?php
    $json = (object)array(
        'stats' => (object)array(
            'scores' => (object)array(
                'score' => 13
            ),
            'kills' => 10,
            'numWins' => 2
        )
    );

    $js = array(
        'Score' => &$json->stats->scores->score,
        'Kills' => &$json->stats->kills,
        'Wins'  => &$json->stats->numWins
        /*         ^ Use the & for references */
    );

    print_r($js);

    $json->stats->kills = 5;

    print_r($js);

    $js['Kills'] = 2;

    var_dump($json->stats->kills);
?>
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [Score] => 13
    [Kills] => 10
    [Wins] => 2
)
Array
(
    [Score] => 13
    [Kills] => 5
    [Wins] => 2
)
int(2)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/gvFy31NS)

Comment: Thanks, I guess that will work fine for me :)